# How to assign value to column based on calculated difference between two DateTime columns?

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

How can I assign the difference between values of the `EventTime` and `CeaseTime` columns to the `MTTR` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQYie.jpg) column as:

```
MTTR = EventTime - CeaseTime
```

I tried to use array, convert `string` value to `DateTime`, but then I don't know how to continue...

```
string[,] column0Array = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count,3];
int i = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    column0Array[i,1] = row.Cells[4].Value != null ? row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
    i++;
    column0Array[i,2] = row.Cells[5].Value != null ? row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
    i++;
}
```

This is the part of the code of a button to add the `MTTR`column.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    var MTTRColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    MTTRColumn.Name = "MTTRColumn";
    MTTRColumn.HeaderText = "MTTR";
    MTTRColumn.ReadOnly = true;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(5, MTTRColumn);
}
```

How can I assign the difference between values of the `EventTime` and `CeaseTime` columns to the `MTTR` column?

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: I really dont' know what i should coe exactly , but what i want is like i wrote " How can I assign the difference between values of the EventTime and CeaseTime columns to the MTTR column as:

MTTR = EventTime - CeaseTime" ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do what you want:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var val1= row.Cells[4].Value + "";

    var val2 = row.Cells[5].Value + "";

    DateTime dt1, dt2;//To store parsed values in dateTime variables

    // try to parse both values in columns
    if(DateTime.TryParse(val1, out dt1) &&
        DateTime.TryParse(val2, out dt2))
    {
        // both values are parsed successfully then assign    
        //computed result of two values in your MTTR column

        row.Cells["MTTR"].Value = (dt1 - dt2) + "";
    }
}
```

Now as you have placed new requirement through your comment, consider the following code which can do the same on button click.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dataGridView1.CurrentRow!-null)
    {
        var row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
        var val1= row.Cells[4].Value + "";                       
        var val2 = row.Cells[5].Value + "";

        DateTime dt1, dt2;//To store parsed values in dateTime variables

        // try to parse both values in columns
        if(DateTime.TryParse(val1, out dt1) &&
            DateTime.TryParse(val2, out dt2))
        {
            // both values are parsed successfully then assign    
            //computed result of two values in your MTTR column

            row.Cells["MTTR"].Value = (dt1 - dt2) + "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format code and add a brief description to help OP understand what he is missing.

Comment: I changed my answer after you added this comment. But I fail to understand why on earth you were creating an array of values of two columns when your objective was to store computed value in MTTR column. Please mark my answer as accepted

Comment: i do it beecause a friend told me to do it , is it possible to calculate mttr directly ? because datagridview is from an excel file

Comment: Now this is very confusing. My answer does that but by direct if you mean that whenever you change value in those two columns your MTTR should reflect? If that is what you want then let me know I can write an answer to do so.

Comment: what i need iss simple : i want to a column in wich it calculated difference between two columns?
here i should - convert string to date time - calculate difference - add result to the new column ..

Comment: Get a clue from the answer. I have already showed you how to parse column values and update MTTM column with computed value. If you want it on column value changed then use dataGridView1.CellValueChanged Event to update MTTM column.